# Connect to cups printer service from windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, printing, network-printer, cups

From windows server 2003 I can easily add a cups printer service from another host:

[image]

I tried the same on a windows server 2008 machine, but I did not succeed to add this kind of http printer addresses there, although the address is reachable in the browser (the cups http interface shows up):

[image]

What is the way to do it on 2008 ?

(I can easily go to the cups http page in a browser from the 2008 machine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is that first IPP (internet printing client) has to be added to the server:

[image]

I rebooted afterwards (maybe restarting the spooling service is enough)

Afterwards it was possible to add the printer as a network printer using the http URL including printer name:

[image]

Entering IPs here works, I did not try using domain names.

Sorry for the mixed localisation in the screenshots

Answer (score 2):

For both 2008 and 2008 R2 it's the same process: on the start menu and type "Add a Printer" then click on the link that's displayed, the Add Printer wizard will open. In the wizard choose add a network printer, then click "the printer I want isn't listed". The next page should allow you to add an http:// or share address for the printer, the UI has changed slightly so that both types of entry are made in the same text-entry box. This process has been tested on Server 2008, 2008 R2 and Windows 7 however I have no cups service so can't test the connectivity.

[image: Windows 7 Cups Printer Dialogue]

Comment: This answer shows the same add printer dialog that I had already included in the question. See the accepted answer for the solution (IPP has to be installed)